# Set valued version of Borsuk Ulam theorem

Tags: gn.general-topology

Assume that  $f,g:S^{2n}\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ are $2$ maps. Assume that the set valued map $p(x)=\{f(x),g(x)\}$  is a continuous set valued map.
Does there exist a point $p\in S^{2n}$ such that $p(x)=p(-x)$?

Comment: For $n=1$ this us reduced to usual Borsuk - - Ulam for the map $x\to (f+g,fg)$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov yes. Very intetesting comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The idea from the comment by Fedor Petrov is suitable for every $n.$ Consider the mapping $F: S^{2n}\to \mathbb{R}^{2n},$ $F(x)=(f(x),g(x)),$ $x\in S^{2n}.$ The Borsuk theorem implies that there exists $x_0\in S^{2n}$ such that $F(x_0)=F(-x_0).$ Obviously, $x_0$ is the desired point.

Comment: we do not know $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ separately